# New to programming, help me understand port scanning

Tags: python-3.x

Below is a sample of code that I've written that forms the iterative part of a port scanner that I'm writing in Python.

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
open_ports_list = []

for i in range(port_min, port_max + 1):
    ipaddress_tup = (ipaddress, i)
    status = sock.connect_ex(ipaddress_tup)

    #executed if connect_ex(ipaddress_tup) is successful 
    if status == 0:
        print('Port',i, 'is OPEN')
        open_ports_list.append(i)

    #executed if connect_ex(ipaddress_tup) is unsuccessful  
    else:
        print('Port',i,'is CLOSED')
```

The scanned system has ports 135 and 136 OPEN, however when I run the above code, it says that port 135 is OPEN and port 136 is CLOSED.

However, if I add:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

into the If block like so:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
open_ports_list = []

for i in range(port_min, port_max + 1):
    ipaddress_tup = (ipaddress, i)
    status = sock.connect_ex(ipaddress_tup)

    #executed if connect_ex(ipaddress_tup) is successful 
    if status == 0:
        print('Port',i, 'is OPEN')
        open_ports_list.append(i)
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    #executed if connect_ex(ipaddress_tup) is unsuccessful  
    else:
        print('Port',i,'is CLOSED')
```

then the code correctly identifies port 135 and 136 as OPEN.

So what is going on here? Why does redefining sock in the if block fix the issue? and can I get the correct port status results without having to redefine sock every time an open port is found?

I've been given a hint from a friend that the detach() function can be used instead, but I don't understand what it does or how to use it.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the operating systems I know of you can successfully connect a socket only once.

You have to create a new socket.